# RequiredFieldValidator in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Any One Can Help.....please
I am Doing In microsoft visual studio 2010,ajax validation callout extender ,Asp.net RequiredFieldValidator i am using in my Page....

I am Using RequiredFieldValidator In All My Text Boxes When i Am My Mouse Leaving The Test Box(Empty)
My RequiredFieldValidator Is Not Coming IF i Click Submit Button Only The RequiredFieldValidator are Coming So Can Any One Help

And I want a regular expression it Must Have Both Characters and Numbers 
Ex:100gb,20kb,like this Number and units of Space,Band width,Sub Domain(right)
100(Error Have to come) 
gd(Error Have to come)

please Help Only using Asp.net And Ajax

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Declare a ValidationGroup on the validation controls and the button click.

the regular expression off the top of my head could be `^((\d{2,3})([\w{2}]))$`
This based on what I can make of your question and the information supplied

Comment: Declare a ValidationGroup on the validation controls and the button click. i try this its Not Working ...pleas help..

Comment: if you edit you post above with the front end code I'm sure myself or someone will be able to help